# Firebug equivalent for Internet Explorer

Tags: debugging, internet-explorer, firefox, webdev.webserver

I am looking for a tool/add-on like Firebug on Firefox ( that is immensely useful for debugging web applications) which works for Internet Explorer. Any suggestions ?

-thanks

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/use-firebug-in-any-browser/  Use Firebug in Any Browser

Answer (score 16):

Microsoft provides the [IE Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=95e06cbe-4940-4218-b75d-b8856fced535) which provides similar functionality to Firebug.

You can also use [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) in IE6+.

Comment: Later versions of IE actually have this built in.  Try pressing F12.

Comment: I think the IE Developer Toolbar is a joke. I isn't at all comparable with Firebug or the WebKit/Chrome Inspector. And I never got Firebug Lite to work. :/

Comment: If you can't get it to work try using the [debug channel](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite#Debug). It forces firebug to show regardless of the environment. This solved it for me in IE9 because the developer toolbar is seen as a version of firebug

Answer (score 1):

Check  this [Firebug Lite For IE](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite). Also there is DebugBar, IE developer toolbar are few other names.

Comment: DebugBar can't debug jQuery UI, don't know about Firebug, but I'm still forced to use Firefox + Firebug for proper debugging

Comment: DebugBar is useless without actual debugging feature!

Answer (score 1):

Also wanted to mention, for network analysis, similar to Firebug's Net tab, I don't think IE dev tools offers as good an alternative. You can then use Fiddler/Fiddler 2 and it's related plugins.

And another option for that that I like is ieHttpHeaders. It won't give you HTTP response body/data but it gives you the HTTP request headers + HTTP POST parameters (excluding file uploads, binary data, and multi-part form POSTs), and HTTP response headers. Good tool to have as companion to your other IE tools.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings and select F12  Developer Tools in IE. I use IE10 and it works.

You can also press F12.

The usage is similar to Firebug. I like this interface more, it shows the color of all color-hex values for easy reference.

Comment: This Works for Internet Explorer 9 and up. Nowadays it is the best solution. You don't need to install anything..

Comment: Yeah but how do you debug Javascript in IE8? I've set breakpoints, but the entire jscript function runs anyway! useless