# IE 8 Testing With Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: html, google-chrome

Well, I am debugging a design which is too messy on IE 8 to IE 10. Its looks great on Chrome, Safari, Opera and Firefox.

The problem i am having is i am easy with Chrome inspect elements and IE 8 developers tools are headache. I am trying to solve problem from last 3 days but no luck because IE Developer tools sucks.

I tried using different tools like, BrowseremAll, IE TAB, TEST IE and BrowserStack.

I am wondering if there is any way to use chrome inspect elements in IE 8 OR there is any Good IE simulator for Chrome?

Please help!

Comment: No, IE8's rendering and javascript engines are completely different (and inferior) to Chrome's. The best you can do is open IE's dev tools and use the "Search HTML" box in the top right to try to find the element you are interested in.

Comment: Did you try FireBug lite for IE too? There is some discussion on this here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395135/firebug-equivalent-for-internet-explorer